# OnPageSelected is never called for first item?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

The problem I faced is that the ViewPager is not calling onPageSelected for the 0 item.
Code sample :

```
public class PagerActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

private static final String TAG = PagerActivity.class.getCanonicalName();

private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pager);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new ViewAdapter());
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    Log.e(TAG, "position = " + position);

}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    Log.e(TAG, "selected page = " + position);

}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    Log.e(TAG, "state = " + state);

}

private class ViewAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.view_pager_item, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.page_indicator);
        textView.setText("Page position = " + position);
        container.addView(viewGroup);
        return viewGroup;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((ViewGroup) object);
    }
}
```

I have no specific task related to that, just wanted to know :

- Is it a known issue and what is the best solution?
- Is it just designed to work this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this under `OnPageChangeListener`

```
pageChangeListener.onPageSelected(0); //Set start to 0 page
```

In your case:

```
PagerActivity.onPageSelected(0);
```

However you should remove the `implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` from the class and add this:

```
OnPageChangeListener pageChangeListener = new OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) { }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) { }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        switch (position) {
        case 0: 
                Log.e(TAG, "selected page = " + position);
            break;

        default:

                Log.e(TAG, "selected page = " + position);
            break;
        }
    }
});
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageChangeListener);
pageChangeListener.onPageSelected(0);
```

Comment: So you mean just set the position before initialization by myself?

Comment: Yes... @YuriiTsap try the full code with pageChangeListener it should work

Comment: I can just make a  check inside the instantiate method if(position==0) onPageSelected(0), but it's not elegant as for me.

Comment: No, cancel implements from class, and add the code above, than you doesn't check position, it starts from 0

Comment: it will work definitely, but it doesn't explain the problem with the 0 element. As asked earlier : is it an intended behavior?

Comment: As I've mentioned also you can do the if-statement inside the instantiateItem method, if you need to have the logic while initializing pager items. But those kind of solutions are workarounds, your one was helpfull. Thanks.